# Last user gets stucked and never ramps down

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, performance-testing, aws

I am running a script on AWS Machine.
I have 30 users and when i run my script last user is likely to never ramp down.
Also, I have cross checked many possible solutions that were on internet which were as follows:

1) Revised my co-relations (found to be satisfactory).
2) Increased jmeter memory.
3) Cleared cache of my project folder and bin folder as well.
4) Revised my test data.
5) Also monitored the CPU and memory of target machine and found that for 30 users it is reaching up-to 100% and in second scenario it is reaching 87%. However it should not be so for 30 users only.

Kindly suggest me where I am doing wrong or is it the application that is making trouble because I have already performed the performance of this application for 600 users and everything seemed to be fine.